# Checkbox not showing up python

Tags: python, user-interface, checkbox, position, tkinter

I am making a GUI that will control a robot.

This is my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import * #Importing TKinter

class Application(Frame): #Making a frame
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title("Vinny's Myro Controller Version 0.1") #Setting the name of the program/window
        self.master.geometry("550x365+300+300") #Window dimensions

        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=2) #how much space the rows take
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) #how much space the columns take

        ''' \/ BOTTOM BUTTONS \/ '''

        self.master.button1 = Button(master, text = "Take a Picture") #Bottom button that is supposed to take a pic.
        self.master.button1.grid(row=6, column=0,  sticky=W+E)

        self.master.button2 = Button(master, text = "Honk the Horn") #Bottom button that is supposed to honk the horn.
        self.master.button2.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W+E)

        self.master.button3 = Button(master, text = "Get Sensor Data") #Bottom button that is supposed to get data from the sensors.
        self.master.button3.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=W+E)

        ''' /\ BOTTOM BUTTONS /\ '''


        ''' \/ LEFT RED FRAME THAT CONTAINS THE ARROWS THAT WILL MOVE THE ROBOT \/ '''

        self.frame1 = Frame(master, bg="red") #Background color
        self.frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = W+E+N+S, padx=10, pady=10) 


        self.frame1.forward = Button(self.frame1, text = "Forward", width=30, height=3) #Forward Button
        self.frame1.forward.place(x=63, y=75) #Button Position

        self.frame1.right = Button(self.frame1, text = "Right", width=12, height=3) #Right Button
        self.frame1.right.place(x=189, y=131) #Button Position

        self.frame1.backward = Button(self.frame1, text = "Backward", width=30, height=3) #Backward Button
        self.frame1.backward.place(x=63, y=187) #Button Position

        self.frame1.left = Button(self.frame1, text = "Left", width=12, height=3) #Left Button
        self.frame1.left.place(x=63, y=131) #Button Position

        ''' /\ LEFT RED FRAME THAT CONTAINS THE ARROWS THAT WILL MOVE THE ROBOT /\ '''

        self.frame2 = Frame(master, bg="green")
        self.frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, rowspan = 3, columnspan = 3, sticky = W+E+N+S, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.frame2.button5 = Button(self.frame2, text = "test")
        self.frame2.button5.grid(row=6, column=2)

        self.frame2.light = BooleanVar()
        self.frame2.chk1 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Lights", variable = self.frame2.light, command = 1+1)
        self.frame2.chk1.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx=10, pady = 10)

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Note this piece of code:

```
self.frame2.light = BooleanVar()
    self.frame2.chk1 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Lights", variable = self.frame2.light, command = 1+1)
    self.frame2.chk1.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx=10, pady = 10)
```

Somehow, I can place a button inside my frame, but not a checkbox. I need this checkbox in order to get data from the robot's sensors.

I've tried using grid and place.

Could anybody help me?

Screenshot:

http://d.pr/i/iRX4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating the checkbutton as a child of `self` rather than as a child of `self.frame2`. Change the checkbutton to be:

```
self.frame2.chk1 = Checkbutton(self.frame2, ...)
```